# How to localize and configure AspNetCore Identity authorization pages in ASP Net Core 3.0.0-preview6

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Application Angular ASP Net Core created on template VS2019 .NetCore 3.0 with authentication and local storage of accounts. I want to customize and localize the authorization page (remove some input fields). How to do this?

Comment: Which page did you want to change and what is your expected result?

Comment: When you create an ASP .Net Core 3.0 project in VS2019 with Angular template with authentication, a SPA project is created. Authorization pages (login, registration)  are offered ready-made, with their own elements and texts. Question: where are them created and how to customize?

Answer (score 0):

For `Asp.Net Core Identity`, it uses [Razor Identity Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio).

- From Solution Explorer, right-click on the project > Add > New Scaffolded Item.
- From the left pane of the Add Scaffold dialog, select Identity > ADD.
- In the ADD Identity dialog, select the options you want.

  - Select your existing layout page, or your layout file will be overwritten with incorrect markup. When an existing _Layout.cshtml file is selected, it is not overwritten.

Change `Areas-> Identity-> Pages->Account->Login.cshtml or Register.cshtml`.

If you hit an error `There was an error running the selected code generator`, create a file `_Layout.cshtml` with empty content in `Pages-> Shared`.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I'll try, is it correct that the Angular project uses Razor ?

Comment: @VasilyAsur For Identity page, it is.

Comment: After all made changes I try to rebuild the project, I get: < can't find the type or name of the namespace "IHostingEnvironment">